# Optimize Custom Drawables

Tags: optimization, android-layout

I'm drawing some custom shapes behind a textview to make it appear it's a notepad.  It draws a repeating bitmap across the top, as well as a white background under the text, and a secondary "note" page under the rest to add a little dimension and layering.  See the screenshot:

[image: ScreenShot]

Now, this is with `setDrawingCacheEnabled(true)` for the TextView this drawable is applied to.  With this method call applied, the scrolling is VERY smooth, exactly what I want.  Without it, the black background disappears, but the scrolling is very choppy.  Any idea on how to cache this view so that scrolling is smooth without destroying my UI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this function only works with solid colors, as defined in the documentation which I *should* have read before posting.  I find it hard to believe there's nothing that caches complex views and drawables to work as well as that function does, but, whatevs. Live 'n learn.